# T-test vs. ANOVA

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, t-test, f-test

With two groups I can either perform ANOVA or T-test. Additionally I can have one-sided test, if I want to make sure I get the same conclusion from both tests and for t-test I choose alpha=0.05, I need to choose an alpha of 0.1 for the ANOVA.
So that means the critical areas are different ? I'm confused because it seems to me they are different but I read somewhere even though I take alpha of 0.1 for ANOVA the my statistical significance stays the same as for the t-test